# Counter Strike 1.6 - Linux Client - Lag spikes

Tags: 13.04, internet, games

I'm having this issue while playing CS 1.6, everything is working well, my ping is normally below 30ms, but every 2 or 3 minutes a huge lag spike affects me, and my ping starts jumping from 30ms to 400ms and back and forth for about 5 / 10 seconds until il stabilizes again.

Anyone have any idea what it might be causing it?

My Hardware information:

> - **Processor Information:**
>
>   **Vendor**:  GenuineIntel
>
>   **Speed**: 2399 Mhz
>
>   4 logical processors /  4 physical processors
>
>   **HyperThreading**:  Unsupported
>
>   **FCMOV**:  Supported
>
>   **SSE2**:  Supported
>
>   **SSE3**:  Supported /  SSSE3:  Supported  /  SSE4a:  Unsupported  /  SSE41:  Unsupported   /  SSE42:  Unsupported
> - **Network Information**:
>
>   **Network Speed**:  Wifi 54Mbps - *(Fiber connection 50 Mbps Down / 10 Mbps Up)*
> - **Operating System Version**:  Ubuntu 13.04 (32 bit)
>
>   **Kernel Name**:  Linux     **Kernel Version**:  3.8.0-22-generic
>
>   **X Server**:
>
>   **Vendor**:  The X.Org Foundation
>     **Release**:  11204000
>     **Manager**:  Compiz
>
>   **Steam Runtime Version**:  steam-runtime-release-i386_2013-05-08
>
> **Video Card**:
>
> **Driver**:  ATI Technologies Inc. ATI Radeon HD 4800 Series
>
> **Driver Version**:  3.3.11672 Compatibility Profile Context
>
> **Desktop Color Depth**: 24 bits per pixel
>
> **Monitor Refresh Rate**: 60 Hz
>
> **VendorID**:  0x1002
>
> **DeviceID**:  0x9442
>
> **Number of Monitors**:  1
>
> **Number of Logical Video Cards**:  1
>
> **Primary Display Resolution**:  1280 x 1024
>
> **Desktop Resolution: 1280 x 1024**
>
> **Primary Display Size**: 13,31" x 10,63"  (17,01" diag)
>
> ```
>                                        33,8cm x 27,0cm  (43,2cm diag)
> ```
>
> * **Primary VRAM Not Detected**
>
> - **Sound card**:
>     Audio device: Realtek ALC662 rev1
> - **Memory**:
>
>   **RAM**:  4033 Mb
> - **Miscellaneous**:
>
>   *UI Language*:  English en_GB.UTF-8
>
>   *Microphone*:  Not set
>
>   *Total Hard Disk Space Available*:  29148 Mb
>
>   *Largest Free Hard Disk Block*:  18924 Mb
> - **Installed software**:
> - **Recent Failure Reports**:

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, there are many options

- internal

  - overheating problems in your machine
  - another program doing heavy networking (torrent search, download, etc)
  - another periodically running service/program
- external

  - other user on the network doing heavy work
  - network hardware issues (overheating switch, cheap router having issues with routing table)
  - Busy server doesn't like you.
  - general shaky internet connection (wireless? someone using the microwave?)

Comment: Thanks for the input Nanne. I think we can pass that options, i monitor the cpu / memory / gpu temperatures and they're stable. This same computer also runs Win7 on dual boot, and while playing on windows it runs smoothly over the same network connection. The ubuntu isn't doing any torrenting / peer2peer, nor any other heavy network job (normally it's just running Counter Strike, sometimes i have a firefox tab open on facebook / gmail whatever, but nothing heavy really. I'm really out of ideas of what it might be... Thanks anyway, cheers :)